# SOAPUI xpath assertion where id changes within tag

Tags: xpath, soapui

I have an error message returned for which I want to use xpath assertion to confirm. The problem is the Transaction Id changes (system generated) while the rest of the information in iongt:faultstring remains constant.

Is there a simple way of doing this assertion?

```
<iongt:retrieveSystemInformationFault xmlns:iongt="http://www.testing.com/xml/TestingIONGT">
      <iongt:faultcode>TestError012</iongt:faultcode>
      <iongt:faultstring>Transaction Id: 8781991797:
Testing error message here</iongt:faultstring>
    </iongt:retrieveCustomerInformationFault>
```

Using an '*' does not work:

```
<iongt:retrieveSystemInformationFault xmlns:iongt="http://www.testing.com/xml/TestingIONGT">
      <iongt:faultcode>TestError012</iongt:faultcode>
      <iongt:faultstring>Transaction Id: *:
Testing error message here</iongt:faultstring>
    </iongt:retrieveCustomerInformationFault>
```

Comment: Please show the XPath you have tried. Please also describe "does not work"; what did it actually do, and how does that differ from what you expected? Third: I'm guessing that the XML you're showing is the error message that you're trying to run an XPath assertion on? If so, I don't understand the point of changing it to put an asterisk in it.

Comment: Hi, because the Transaction ID is changing (system generated number) the xpath assertion fails as what was recorded does not match what was received. I tried using * and wildcard for the Transaction ID but this does not work as the xpath assertion tries to literally check for "Transaction ID: *" Testing error message here". If I use wildcard for the entire tag then this works e.g. <iongt:faultstring>*</iongt:faultstring>

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not clear: what are the XML bits that you posted - are they the XML error message you're trying to match, or do they contain the XPath assertion? They look like the former, but if so, please show us the XPath.

Comment: The first lot of XML in my original post is what I receive when I run my request. The second lot is my effort at setting up the XPATH MATCH assertion. I am using the * to try to handle the system generated Transaction ID value.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I'm still really confused by the fact that your second snippet looks like XML, yet you say it's an XPath match assertion. Maybe it's just my ignorance about SOAPUI. Ah... I bet your second snippet is actually the "Expected Result" (http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/xpath-and-xquery-assertions.html#1-1-wildcards), not the XPath expression itself. Now I'm starting to understand...

Comment: That being the case, please show us your XPath expression ... the stuff you have in the upper text box on the XPath Match configuration dialog. Also, I assume you have "Allow wildcards" checked. Ultimately, I suspect the answer is that SoapUI XPath Match Expected Result wildcards have to match entire text nodes, not part of one. You can overcome that, but that will be an answer rather than a comment. And it will still help if you show your XPath Expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that SoapUI XPath Match Expected Result wildcards have to match entire text nodes, not part of one.

Of course, you could just assert at a less precise level, by using an asterisk for the whole text content in your Expected Result (as you mentioned this works):

```
<iongt:faultstring>*</iongt:faultstring>
```

But if you need to be more precise, you could also modify your XPath expression as follows. Instead of just

```
//iongt:retrieveSystemInformationFault
```

for example, you could have this XPath Expression:

```
//iongt:retrieveSystemInformationFault/iongt:faultcode
```

with an Expected Result of

```
<iongt:faultcode xmlns:iongt="http://www.testing.com/xml/TestingIONGT">TestError012</iongt:faultcode>
```

and another assertion with XPath expression

```
//iongt:retrieveSystemInformationFault/iongt:faultstring[starts-with(., 'Transaction Id: ') and
   contains(., 'Testing error message here')]
```

I'm suggesting `contains()` here because XPath 1.0 doesn't have `ends-with()`. If you really need to get precise, instead of just `contains()`, you could substitute an equivalent for `ends-with()` using `string-length()` and `substring()`, but I doubt that level of effort is necessary.

The expected result for the above would be just

```
<iongt:faultstring xmlns:iongt="http://www.testing.com/xml/TestingIONGT">*</iongt:faultstring>
```

Or you could combine the two into one assert ... let me know if you want to see an example of that.